# React-router - hide component from main URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this router:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={Auth} />
      <Route path="/register" component={RegisterForm} />
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
    </div>
  </Router>
  ), document.getElementById('app'));
```

And that's the auth component:

```
class Auth extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="auth">
        <header>
          <h2>Login / Register</h2>
        </header>

        <ul className="auth__list">
          <li className="button auth__button"><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
          <li className="button auth__button"><Link to="/register">Register</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

When I go to http://my-project/ it shows `Auth` component.

But when I click on "Register" or "Login" links it's showing "RegisterForm" or "LoginForm" components *below* the Auth component, while in my opinion /register should show only RegisterForm and /login should show only /LoginForm.

My question is:

- why is the "Auth" component being rendered on /register and /login by default?
- what's the best way to get rid of it on these pages?

Unfortunately react-router's webpage doesn't help, because they stick navigations above every example and it's confusing to me :(

Thanks a lot.

### UPDATE

That's how I import the router, maybe that's the issue?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
(...)

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: what react router version are you using? If it's react-router v4 then add this 

`<Route path="/" exact component={Auth} /> `

Comment: 4.1.1, as soon as I add `exact` my application renders blank page, no console.log / react devtool errors, it just simply stops working. I'm updating my original question, maybe I'm importing something wrong?

Comment: take a look at this: http://codepen.io/ashafir20/pen/qmmgQo?editors=1010

Comment: @radix remove `<Link to="/">Auth</Link>` and you're exactly in my situation. I'm booting up the app, it's open and I can see nothing yet I'm at "/". I guess I need to push my component above Router to display it on index page or something?